# Форма регистрации без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать, чтобы форма регистрации при нажатии на "Отправить" на странице не перезагружалась?

Answer (score 2):

Подключите [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/):

> jQuery Form Plugin позволяет легко и ненавязчиво обновлять HTML-формы с использованием AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Поставить у кнопки тип button и подключить ajax

Answer (score 1):

Если не хочется прикручивать плагины, а форма не рассчитана для загрузки файлов, как вариант можно сделать вот так:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function anyfunction(form_obj){
  $.ajax(  ... form_obj.serialize(); .... }
  return false;
}
</script>
<form onSubmit='anyfunction(this);'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно проще - сделайте див с абсолютным позиционированием и напишите что display:hide; обработчик по кнопке - показать или скрыть, обработка полей в поп-апе на js, естественно задаем ему z-index больше чем у всех.